# Apps like Twitch asking for Firewall exceptions: are we at risk of having our computer hacked?

Tags: firewalls, twitch

I am installing the Twitch app, and a firewall warning popped up asking that I give permissions to use the app via private and/or public networks.

I am a security newbie but a bit paranoid and wonder what are the risks of allowing the app to run freely with a firewall exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the situation:

- If you're adding a firewall exception for outgoing connections made by twitch, I don't see a problem - That's just normal if your firewall is very restrictive.
- If you're adding an exception for inbound connections that of course enlarges your attack surface, but I would not be paranoid about it (unless you're running in a high security environment). - Rather make sure, that you constantly update your twitch installation in order to get security updates, and you should be fine.